# Настройка htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

перерыл кучу статей по настройке htaccess, но так и не нашел ответа на свой вопрос.
Мне нужно перенаправлять URL таким образом:
Если url /main, то страница бралась с /pages/main.php
Если url /forum/1/, то страница бралась с /pages/forum.php, но с GET параметром ?page=1, ну думаю суть ясна.
Заранее, спасибо за ответы.

Comment: примерно так `RewriteRule ^/forum/([0-9]+)$ /pages/forum.php?page=$1`

Comment: @Talleyran Странно, мне пишет 404.